# Android: how to center a button programatically created?

Tags: android

I need to create a button programatically and have it centered on the layout, both horizontally and vertically. I am trying with the following code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutItem);
Button b = new Button(this);        
b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
ll.addView(b);
```

But it's not working. The button comes out on top all to the left.

Any clues on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to set the `LayoutParams` of the `LinearLayout` instead of the `LayoutParams` of the `Button` itself

Comment: The params of the LinearLayout are set via XML. And if I don't set the params of the button it will be inflated to fill the parent.

Comment: Why not just center it in the XML file?

Comment: @Juice, cause I need to create the buttom programatically to add it to the layout after I have added other stuff (i.e., the order is important).

Comment: Is there a set number of buttons? But the order of them matters?

Comment: No, I just need to add this button after a customListView, and I can't put the listView via XML cause it uses a custom class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)b.getLayoutParams();    
ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
b.setLayoutParams(ll);
```

see if that works.

Answer (score 10):

Or you can use a `RelativeLayout` as your parent `View` and do the following:

```
this.testButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.testButton);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams testLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

testLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

this.testButton.setLayoutParams(testLP);
```

You can set several rules for the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep this in mind as an alternative solution. The one above worked like a charm though.

Comment: Yeah, i was in the process of posting the answer when he did. Just thought i would post this one too... since the `RelativeLayout` gives you more freedom in laying out your `Views` in weird ways... instead of just vertical or horizontal.