# How to set Layout Gravity to center|right programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

I can set the gravity of my element as `center|right` or `center|left` in **xml** like :

```
android:layout_gravity="center|left"
```

but how can i do that **programatically**?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11657698/1021695

Answer (score 2):

```
view1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: There's no `View.setGravity()` and `layout_gravity` is a layout concept, not view concept.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more readable code:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Comment: I'm assigning the LayoutParams to elements not layouts

Comment: Can you specify what you need? It's hard to help you if you keep adding information after the we answer your incomplete question

Comment: I'm taking about a general concept of LayoutParams

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: There's no `View.setGravity()` and `layout_gravity` is a layout concept, not view concept.